mount read-only host directory with only group access
I'm using podman as user john, member of data group, (rootless, then) to start a container where the only user is the non-root contjohn user.
On the host, /mnt/db is a directory of permissions root:data rwxr-x--- full of very large files that john can only read. I want contjohn to access those files via /data/db inside the container.
So, my first try :
podman run --rm --userns keep-id -v /mnt/db:/data/db:ro imagename ./run

However, when i'm entering the container and trying accessing the mounted volume, i get a permission error, for a reason : the mounted volume belong to nobody.
$ ls -l /data/
drwx------. 4 nobody nogroup 4096 Mar 27 18:05 db

I tried using the U flag (-v /mnt/db:/data/db:ro,U), but as john i can't modify host's files (and even if i could, that's not the point) :
Error: failed to chown recursively host path: lchown /mnt/db: operation not permitted

I tried uidmap and gidmap parameters, without success :
$ podman run --rm --uidmap 1065:@1043:1 --gidmap 1065:@1045:1 -v /mnt/db:/data/db:ro imagename ./run
<error: initializing ID mappings: UID setting is malformed expected ["uint32:uint32:uint32"]: ["1065:@1065"]

I tried multiple combinations of various parameters (--userns keep-id:uid=1043,gid=1045, --user john:data, --group-add keep-groups) without ever arriving in a state where i can read files as contjohn just like i read them with john.
I obviously don't have a clue about how podman handles volumes. How can i read those read-only files from inside a podman container ?
(podman version is 4.6.1)

Note syntax --gidmap 1065:@1045:1  was introduced in podman 4.7.0 https://github.com/containers/podman/pull/18713/commits/91b8bc7f13f9757dc57738a05923dc3c9c6d3190   Also sometimes ls -l will show nobody as the group despite the fact that --group-add keep-groups fixes the permission problem. In other words, the best test is to try to read/write and see if the operation succeeds.

I posted somewhat of a solution at https://stackoverflow.com/a/79159138/4784914
